# Do I Have to Change Internal Interrupt Setups when I Change Clock Speed?

Tags: interrupt, atmega328, arduino-pro-mini, oscillator-clock

Do I Have to Change Internal Interrupt Setups when I Change Clock Speed? The reason I ask is because I am trying to modify this code:

https://github.com/DccPlusPlus/BaseStation/blob/master/DCCpp_Uno/DCCpp_Uno.ino (Beginning at Line 289)

so that if will work on an ATmega328P-derivative board running at 3.3V and 8 MHz. I need the waveforms to be generated at the same speed, so is there anything I have to change? The original code is written for a 16 MHz uno or mega.

Comment: Yes, you will have to recalculate all the timer compare values (halve them for half the clock speed?)

Comment: Halve the values and round _down_: 3199 → 1599, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for timer period is given by the following formula, where `N` is the value of the prescaler, `TOP` is the value given by either `MAX` (i.e. `0xFF`, `0xFFFF`) or the value in register `OCRnx`, and `f` is the frequency of the I/O clock.

[image: T = (N × (TOP+1)) ÷ f]

If you're using phase-correct or phase- and frequency-correct mode, the factor (`TOP`+1) in the formula above should be replaced by 2 × `TOP`.

Comment: It's not `TOP`. It's either 2 × `TOP` (in the phase-correct and phase-and-frequency-correct PWM modes) or `TOP` + 1 (in any other mode).